# Running rails server changes test result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, reactjs, phantomjs, capybara

Related with this question, I came across a strange situation.
[ruby on rails - Log in test fails with RSpec / Capybara / Poltergeist - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34695237/log-in-test-fails-with-rspec-capybara-poltergeist/34695329#34695329)

### Just run test

`bin/rspec spec/features/spec.rb`

```
11871 spring server | myapp | started 32 secs ago
11877 spring app    | myapp | started 31 secs ago | test mode
```

I get log from PhantomJS like:

```
API.ajax:GET /user :failed
httpStatus:0
error
undefined
```

### Run test with server running in development

`bin/rails s`
and then
`bin/rspec spec/features/spec.rb`

I get log from PhantomJS like:

```
API.ajax:POST /sessions :failed
httpStatus:401
error
[object Object]
```

It looks like PhantomJS can't even reach the /sessions url without server running in development. (It fails anyway though..)

Does anyone have same experience? I don't know why running dev server makes this change and hope there is a clue to resolve the test failure.

I'm using RSpec, Cabybara, Poltergeist, PhantomJS 2.0 and **React**.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dev server runs on port 3000 while Capybara runs the test server on a random port unless you've set Capybara.server_port.  From your description it sounds like you may have a reference to port 3000 hard coded into your JS, which would mean it wasn't it's trying to contact the dev server even when running in test mode

Comment: It was indeed hard coded! In the app, some functionality refer hard coded port 3000 that I can't change now because it's not my app. As a work around, I've set Capybara.serve_port = 3000. Of course it's annoying I can't run dev server while test is running. But for now it would work.
Thanks a lot!